# Dot net core app to databricks SQL connectivity issue in docker

Tags: azure, docker, .net-core, ssl-certificate, unixodbc

I am facing below issue in my dotnet core app while running it in a container on one of the Azure VM -

> General Exception: System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException (0x80131937): ERROR [08S01] [Simba][Hardy] (115) Connection failed with error: SSL_read: Interrupted system call
> at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.HandleError(OdbcHandle hrHandle, SQLRETURN retcode)
> at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, Boolean needReader, Object[] methodArguments, SQL_API odbcApiMethod)
> at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, Boolean needReader)
> at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

Same app is working fine on host VM machine but while running it in docker container its throwing above.
I have tried SSL certificate but nothing really worked.

same app is working fine while running on local machine or even in a container on local machine.

I have already tried ssl certificate and also everything is working fine with isql command and odbc connection.
strange issue is that even simple select query to a table is also working but in case of a sql function call its throwing above errors